# How to execute command line file on remote server?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh

I have a staging script where I want to execute some operations on the remote machine.

But when I use `ssh ${REMOTEUSER}@${REMOTEHOST}` the next line `mkdir folder`won't work. The script stops and I end um in the Command Line of the remote server. How do I get the other commands running there?

Comment: Take a look at ssh's man page...

Comment: I've been searching for this like an hour. Could you provide Link or example?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of the script that you're trying to get working.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this, my bad. I added an answer with a suggestion which _might_ be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply "continue" some script you started by opening a ssh connection on the remote side. Those are two completely separate processes. What you *can* do is push a local script into a remote shell you initiate by opening the ssh connection:

```
ssh user@remoteSystem 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
```

This assumes that `local_script.sh` is a valid bash script stored in a local file, obviously.